# Does "more than" mean "over"?

Tags: meaning

> More than one student know the answer.

Does it means "***Over one student knows the answer***" , why or why not?

Comment: It is clear that both can be mostly used interchangeably when placed near numbers. For example- *I gave you more than what you needed* is correct and *I gave you over what you needed* is incorrect. However, there is a slight distinction for when to use either one of them along with numbers. Refer to this grammar girl article for more info - http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/more-than-versus-over

Comment: "Over one student" sounds much less natural than "more than one student", though.

Comment: "over" sounds better with larger numbers (maybe over 20 in my mind). When I think of usages I have heard this is usually the case.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the context, *more than* means *over or above* *especially* if the former is followed by some **number.** However, you cannot interchange these both everywhere (see Invoker's useful comment).

> More than 300 people gathered at the event = Over 300 people gathered at the event

See this (#5) -

> [Over](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/over_1) - above; more

However, take a note that the adverb *overly* may not **exactly** mean *more than.* There, it's *exceeding* the limit.

> [overly](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/OVERLY) - To a degree exceeding normal or proper limits

Also, the *[prefix over-](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=over)* means excessively, beyond or extreme